# Python Requests and 404 error with Django/tasty-pie

Tags: python, tastypie, python-requests

I have a Django app that's serving up a RESTful API using tasty-pie.

I'm using Django's development `runserver` to test.

When I access it via a browser it works fine, and using Curl also works fine:

```
curl "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/host/?name__regex=&amp;format=json"
```

On the console with runserver, I see:

```
[02/Oct/2012 17:24:20] "GET /api/v1/host/?name__regex=&amp;format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 2845
```

However, when I try to use the Python requests module (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), I get a 404 as the output:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/host/?name__regex=&format=json')
>>> r
<Response [404]>
```

or:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/host/?name__regex=&amp;format=json')
>>> r
<Response [404]>
```

Also, on the Django runserver console, I see:

```
[02/Oct/2012 17:25:01] "GET http://localhost:8000/api/v1/host/?name__regex=&format=json HTTP/1.1" 404 161072
```

For some reason, when I use requests, it prints out the whole request URL, including localhost - but not when I use the browser, or curl.

I'm assuming this is something to do with the encoding, user-agent or request type it's sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Requests, but I think your encoding idea might be sound. That is Requests might process the URL somehow? Perhaps instead of passing everything in the URL directly, try doing what [Requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) suggest:

```
request_params = { 'name_regex' : '', 'format' : 'json' }
r = requests.get( 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/host/', params = request_params )
```